# Spel expression method argument property placeholder

Tags: spring, properties, oauth-2.0, spring-el

I am trying to access the value of a spring application property inside a spel expression but it seems impossible to me. I am trying to put a prefix before an oauth2 scope so when PreAuthorize happens the full scope name will be prefix+"something" so it can be dynamically changed in the future:

`@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope(${prefixes.someprefix}+'/stock.r')")`

Every example in the spel documentation seems hello world type and others are only using property accessing in @Value annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@PreAuthorize` processor does not resolve property placeholders.

Since you are invoking `oauth2.hasScope`, you could create a wrapper that applies the prefix (from a property) before delegating to the real method.